# Black box flashes across bootstrap carousel on firefox for android

Tags: android, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

We're doing some final testing on a responsive design and we've discovered an issue on our homepage carousel, but it's only happening on Firefox for Android - not Chrome for Android, not Firefox desktop (not even in responsive design mode), and not on any iOS devices.

Anytime the carousel rotates, either automatically or manually, a black box flashes across the middle after the new slide appears. It is only there for less then a second, then it disappears. I managed to capture a screenshot of it after a few carefully timed attempts:

[image: Black box across Bootstrap carousel slide on Firefox for Android]

Here is a webpage that demonstrates the issue: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9530717/firefox-android-black-box/index.html

I know it's occurring at some point in the `Carousel.prototype.slide` function (somewhere between [line 144](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js#L144) and [line 164](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js#L164) in the source on Github), but I have no idea what element it's occurring on or what specific line is triggering it. I've tried stepping through it in Firefox's remote debugger to no avail.

FWIW, the black box does not occur when viewing the stock [Bootstrap carousel demo](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) in Firefox for Android.

We are using the latest version of Bootstrap (3.2.0).

Comment: It seems like the black band is coming from .home-slideshow .carousel-control in the main.css. From your screenshot, the band appears to be a container that holds the carousel navigation, this seems to align with the class I mention. Look at the height defined for the class, 37px, that looks in line with what you're seeing. Perhaps you can try adding a class style override for the RGBA value, or write a media query specific to the Android to address this?

Comment: In some cases it does appear to be related to that section, but in some of my tests the flash covers the whole section, and in others it's just the top left. And in any case, it doesn't stick around long enough for me to see what changes to make it flash, nor can i find the code that triggers it.  I posted an issue to the Bootstrap github account after finding the same issue on carousels on other websites, but they punted and said it's a mozilla issue. I created almost 2 dozen test sites to demonstrate and try to track it down, but the results were always unpredictable.

Comment: Unfortunate that it does not sound like it's a totally reproducible issue. From a different bug (#14720 - possible carousel bug on Android 4.2) filed on Bootstrap github, they state "note that we don't officially support the non-Chrome Android stock browser". Perhaps take a look at Bug 1005694 (URL = https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1005694) which sounds similar to your bug. Maybe you can append to that bug or file a new one for this issue there, since it sounds browser specific.